# Connect DBUS Service method to another method

Tags: python, dbus

I have 4 DBUS Services python script (a.py,b.py,c.py,d.py) and Run it in 'main.py'

The Reason why i want to merge dbus services, is because of %Memory per process running. 2.0% Memory per dbus service. I'll create a 15 of dbus services.

main.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import gobject
from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop

listofdbusfilenames = ['a','b','b','d']

def importDbusServices():
    for dbusfilename in listofdbusfilenames:
        globals()[dbusfilename] = __import__(dbusfilename) 

def callservices():
    for dbusfilename in listofdbusfilenames:
        globals()[dbusfilename +'_var'] =  eval(dbusfilename +'.ServiceClass()')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    importDbusDervices()
    DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default = True)
    callservices()
    loop = gobject.MainLoop()
    loop.run()
```

***a.py wants to get the return method from b.py***

***b.py will get the return method of c.py and d.py***

-a.py

--|b.py

----|c.py

----|d.py

The PROBLEMS:

1. I can't get the return method ''get_dbus_method'', **Introspect Error** appears.
2. I tried signal and receiver BUT it takes longer than ''get_dbus_method''.

my dbus service format

```
import dbus
import dbus.service
class ServiceClass(dbus.service.Object):    
    def __init__(self):

        busName = dbus.service.BusName('test.a', bus = dbus.SystemBus())
        dbus.service.Object.__init__(self, busName, '/test/a')
    @dbus.service.method('test.a')
    def aMethod1(self):
            #get the b.py method value 'get_dbus_method' here
            return #value from b.py method
```

*Is there any other way to get the method directly?*

*Thanks in advance for response and reading this. :D*